# initiating global variables in different translation units (linker involved)

Tags: c++, linker, initialization, global-variables

I am reviewing C++ lately. Here is my question. See the code in `file1.cpp` and `file2.cpp`.

file1.cpp

```
int x1 = 1;
int y1 = x1 + 2;
```

file2.cpp

```
#include "necessary_headers"
extern int y1;
int y2 = y1 + 2;
int main()
{
    cout << "y2 is "<<y2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile in the different order :

```
gcc file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

the output is `y2 is 5`, of course.

```
gcc file2.cpp file1.cpp
```

the output is `y2 is 2`.(My question is about this)

I also try this : `gcc file2.cpp`. And this gives `undefined reference to y1`, of course.

My question is, why would `gcc file2.cpp file1.cpp` compile rather than giving `undefined reference to y1` error even if the linking sequence is "wrong"? Is it because that when linking `file2.cpp`, the linker is smart to refers to `y1` which is defined in the following file `file1.cpp`? And in this way, `y1` is initialized to 0(default value) in `file2.cpp` rather than using the definition in `file1.cpp`? So in this way, isn't the definition and initialization in `file1.cpp` `"int y1 = x1 + 2"` invalidated by the linking sequence? If not,how can I execute that statement to assign `y1 = x1 + 2`? Finally, is this a general compiler behavior? According to c++ standard, the order to initializing global variables in different translation units is undefined.

Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: `extern int x` does not mean "the variable `x` is defined somewhere else", but "the symbol 'x' has external linkage". (You can write `extern int y2 = y1 + 2;` if you want to.)

Comment: The order of initialisation of `y1` and `y2` - since they are dynamically initialised in different compilation units - is *unspecified* by the standard.    So the two behaviour you see are permitted, but neither is required   i.e.  it is not a "general compiler behaviour", in the sense that all compilers/linkers are not required to give the same effect - and practically do not.    If you want a specific order of initialisation, you need to force that (e.g. by placing definition and initialisation of both `y2` and `y1` in the same compilation unit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, why would gcc file2.cpp file1.cpp compile rather than
>   giving undefined reference to y1 error even if the linking sequence is
>   "wrong"?

From [basic.link#2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#2.1)

> When a name has *external* linkage, the entity it denotes **can be
>   referred to by names from scopes of other translation units** or from
>   other scopes of the same translation unit.

Thus, `extern int y1;` is not undefined if you compile the file (eg. file1.cpp) which contains the definition of `y1`.

For during linking, the definition of `y1` is checked from other translation units.