# Initialize global variable using extern global variable

Tags: c++

Assume `file_1.cpp` and `file_2.cpp` are two files in one program. I encountered situation as follows:

```cpp
// file_1.cpp
extern int y;  // Line 1
int z = y + 1;  // Line 2
int main() {
  cout << y << endl;  // 2
  cout << z << endl;  // probably 1, sometimes 3
}

// file_2.cpp
int x = 1;  // Line 3
int y = x + 1;  // Line 4
```

My understanding is that, when the execution constructs global variables before it enters `main()`, depending on the optimization setting, there is a possibility that the global variables in `file_1.cpp` are constructed prior to the global variables in `file_2.cpp`. In such case, the value of `y` is set to `0` when it is used to initialize `z`, and thus `cout << z << endl;` prints `1`. `Line 4` will be executed when the global variables in `file_2.cpp` are constructed before entering `main()`, so we still have `cout << y << endl;` printing out `2`.

My question: to my knowledge, `extern int y;` is a declaration without definition (it does not allocate memory, it does not really create the object, it just introduces the name into the program). So, I would like to know what precisely happens at `Line 1`/`Line 2` (in case `cout << z << endl;` prints out `1`). Is `y` really being defined and initialized to `0` there? Or is that just an optimization behavior done by the compiler/linker such that (during the initialization of `z`) whenever the token `y` is seen, it is replaced by the value `0`?

If `y` is really being defined (and initialized to `0`) at `Line 1`/`Line 2`, it confuses me because it contradicts to my understanding that `extern int y;` is just a declaration, and in that case I wonder how compiler/linker avoid redefinition when `Line 4` is executed later.

I know that in real program, the code above is what we should avoid, but I just really want to know its implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initiating global variables in different translation units (linker involved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013784/initiating-global-variables-in-different-translation-units-linker-involved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you describe is known as "global initialization order *fiasco*".

When a program starts, the memory for all global variables is filled with 0s (that is, each byte is 0). In the next stage, constructors or initializations for all global variables are executed. The order of those initializations within each file is determined by the order of variables *definitions* in that file, but the order of files is arbitrary.

In your example, `y` is initialized in `file_2.cpp`. If initialization of the variables defined in `file_1.cpp` is executed before `file_2.cpp`, you get `z==1`.

`extern int y;` in line 1 is, indeed, unrelated to the initialization order - it just allows to access `y` in `file_1.cpp`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) So can I understand it this way?: global variables in all translation units are defined and initialized to 0s (bytes) as soon as the program starts, and later, each global variable is assigned with the value provided in the initializer when its definition in the source code (like `Line2,3,4`) is executed

Comment: Yes, this is a good summary.